# Output Buffering Not Displaying Error Notice

Tags: php, error-handling, output-buffering

In my PHP script I had errors turned onto E_ALL. Then around my views I add an output buffer that starts and ends with ob_start()/ob_flush. The problem I am having now is Notices will not be displayed if they occur but Fatal errors will.

Does anyone have an idea why this is happening and how it can be changed?

If it matters, I am running PHP 5.3.3 on a Centos 6 server with Apache.

Comment: output buffering doesn't disable or hide errors; you probably have changed some setting elsewhere which hides errors from you.

Comment: No, I'm in a MVC. The front end controller has error_reporting(E_ALL); All I did is wrap the views in an output buffer. I want the Notices to be displayed to help me debug, not to turn them off.

Comment: Still, output buffering doesn't disable or hide errors, warnings or notices.. Even though you told the frontend controller that error_reporting should be enabled, settings from the server can override this. Which propably is the case.

Comment: I'm actually experiencing the same issue -- I'm generating a hand-rolled MVC model, and somehow the output buffer functions are masking the errors from my browser.  Disable the output functions, and all the errors show up; enable them, and somehow they vanish.  It's as if ob_get_clean is getting from only the current buffer, but wiping previous buffers.  (Interestingly enough, I'm at a buffer level of '2' despite only actually calling buffers once)

Comment: Oh, just to add,it's not just errors that get masked; so do my own 'echo' statements (or var_dump) that I put into functions to debug why they aren't working as expected.

Comment: RonLugge, have you had any progress figuring out why it's doing this with yours?

Answer (score 1):

Edit your php.ini:

1. Be sure you have the proper `error_level` set (see: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php).
2. Make sure `display_errors` is set to On in dev/test environments and Off on production environment.
3. Set `log_errors=/tmp/phperrors.log`.

Then you should be covered.